# How to use Drupal-IOS API (Kyle Browning's). How to get the parameter to be pass as post data while calling any rest API in drupal?

Tags: iphone, drupal-7

I am developing an IOS application which using the server communication from Drupal based server. I did implement DIOS API and login successfully.

I stucked in updating user details like : email, password, user image etc. These requires current password with other updated details to be send via post data. Is there any way to find key-value pairs to set in post parameters and we would like to know the general mechanism  (if there is any) of knowing the post parameters i.e. keys for different Drupal APIs for different functions?

Following are the details of environment and sdk versions I am working with:

- DIOS sdk version:  workhabitinc-drupal-ios-sdk-7.x-3.x-1.1b-8-g401c3fc
- Drupal Version: drupal-7.2
- Drupal Services module version: 7.x-3.0-rc3
- Drupal Chaos tools module version: 7.x-1.0-beta1
- Drupal REST Server module version: 7.x-3.0-rc3
- Drupal REST Server plist support module version: 7.x-1.0
- Drupal XMLRPC Server module version: 7.x-3.0-rc3
- Mac OS version: 10.6.7
- Xcode version:3.2.5 (IOS 4.2)

could you help me to find the signature of various various rest API and function .  is there any documents available which explain what parameter we should pass while calling any rest API in drupal?

Thanks in Advance,